# How to justify that after a particular $N$ a convergent sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ is constant

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, continuity

Let $X=Y:=\mathbb R$ and define the two topological spaces $(X,\tau_{1})$ and $(Y,\tau_{2})$ where $\tau_{2}$ is the topology generated by the euclidean metric on $\mathbb R$ and $\tau_{1}:=\{\mathbb R, \varnothing\}\cup\{\mathbb R\setminus A:A \operatorname{ countable}\}$

Background: I want to show that any function $F:X\to Y$ is sequentially continuous

and I have come to the conclusion that in case of convergence (say, sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$) in $\tau_{1}$ that after a particular $N$ the sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ is constant. But I have not found a way to prove this fact. Any ideas? After this fact, sequential continuity is a breeze.

Further: How can I show that the identity is not continuous?

Comment: If $x_n \to x$ in $\tau_1$, then since $U:= \mathbb{R}\setminus \{x_n : x_n \not = x\}$ is an open set containing $x$, it must be that $x_n \in U$ for large $n$, i.e. $x_n = x$ for large $n$.

Comment: The identity is not continuous because the preimage of the open set $(-1,1)$ is not open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x_n \to x$. Define $U= \Bbb R \setminus \{x_n: x_n \neq x\}$. This set is open (as its complement is $\{x_n: x_n \neq x\}$, which is a subset of the terms of a sequence, so at most countable.). It also contains $x$ as by definition $x \notin \{x_n: x_n \neq x\}$.

By the definition of convergence, there is some $N \in \Bbb N$ such that

$$\forall n \ge N: x_n \in U$$

And note that $x_n \in U$ iff $x_n \notin \{x_n: x_n \neq x\}$ iff $x_n =x$.

So in fact

$$\forall n \ge N: x_n = x$$

as required.

Finally, the identity $F: (\Bbb R, \tau_1) \to (\Bbb R, \tau_2)$ is not continuous, as $(0,1) \in \tau_2$ and $F^{-1}[(0,1)] = (0,1)$ is not open in $\tau_1$, as its complement is uncountable.